# SQL Server running as docker container on Macbook. I am unable to connect with python

Tags: python, sql-server, macos, pyodbc

I am trying to connect to a SQL SERVER database that is running as a docker container on my macbook.  I am able to connect to the database using Azure Data Studio.  I have been unsuccessful in connecting via sqlcmd as well from my local macbook.  When I open a python3 interactive session from my local macbook and type:

```
import pyodbc 
pyodbc.drivers()
```

I get the following output:

```
['ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server']
```

So I think my driver is setup correctly.  The README_NOTES files says the specific driver version is 17.10.1.1.

I then try to setup a connection string using something like this:

```
cnxn_str = ("Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=localhost;Database=test;UID=SA;PWD=my_password;")
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(cnxn_str)
```

And I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Any help figuring out what the issue is would be appreciated.

I have already created a docker bridge network and inspected the network and got the IP address 172.20.0.2.  I have also used that IP address in place of localhost with the same result.

Here is my docker container:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                        COMMAND                  CREATED        STATUS      PORTS                    NAMES
ab983a860cc5   mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest   "/opt/mssql/bin/perm…"   2 months ago   Up 5 days   0.0.0.0:1433->1433/tcp   sql_server
```

Comment: `localhost` is unlikely to be the right way to connect to a Docker container, unless you have some really weird routing setup. You need to find the right IP or DNS name, as well as the mapped port number

Comment: I have created a docker bridge network with my container id and inspected that network to find the ip address was 192.20.0.2 and replaced localhost with that, but I get the same response.

Comment: Have you mapped the correct port? I believe you need to open the firewall for that port

Comment: Did you publish any ports from the container? e.g.: if you were using `docker run ...` then you'd normally include `-p 1433:1433` to expose the container's tcp/1433 port on the host's tcp/1433 port. Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73926811/edit) your question to show how you launched the container, e.g.: a docker-compose.yml file, etc.

Comment: Where is the Python code running? On the Docker host, or inside another Docker container? From a networking perspective Docker containers are essentially their own little linux VMs, so referencing `localhost`, `127.0.0.1` or `::1` is actually addressing the container itself and will only connect to services running inside the container. If you need to connect to services running on the host, or published from another container in a different Docker network, you could try using `host.docker.internal` as the target.

Comment: The python code is running from the local macbook, not from another docker container.  The docker container is only running SQL Server.

Comment: What specific version of ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server do you have installed? If you're on an Arm-based (M1/M2) system, for example: you need 17.8 or later installed to be accessible from Arm-based processes; if you installed 17.7 or earlier (which you could only do from an x64-emulated Terminal) that driver would only be available to x64-emulated processes.

Comment: I used the instructions from Microsoft from the site "Install the Microsoft ODBC driver for SQL Server (macOS)" which uses brew install.   I found the README_NOTES from the documentation and it says "17.10.1.1 - 2022-06-30".  I am using an intel based Macbook.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that since I am using a company laptop they had the firewall locked down and the docker application was not included in the list of firewall exceptions.  Once I was able to gain access to the firewall settings, I was able to add the docker application to the firewall exception list and I was able to connect via python and sqlcmd on local port 1433 mapped to my docker container using "localhost,1433"

Thank you to the community for working through this issue with me.